# Close Eclipse Application Programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse Application that I want to close. The catch is that it is a headless application, so I can not use the following method:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close();
```

What alternative can I use to close the application cleanly?

My main plugin, the one that defines the product and the application, contains the following dependencies:

- org.eclipse.core.runtime

And that is about it.

I use the extension points:

- org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications

To define my app.

I create a Swing UI for it, and I want to be able to close the application after a certain process is done, or as a result of a user action.  I wonder if there is any API in Eclipse to do that, or in this case that I handle the UI on my own, do I have to close the application by exiting on the class that implements IApplication.

Answer (score 1):

May be using [`ResourcesPlugin`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin.java.htm) services?

See [this class](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.gmf/plugins/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.ui/src/org/eclipse/gmf/runtime/common/ui/plugin/XToolsUIPlugin.java?root=Modeling_Project&view=co) for an example of stop method (I know it is an [AbstractUI](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin.java.htm) class, but it is basically a [Plugin](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin.java.htm), and if you have such a class deriving from Plugin, you can implement the [`org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.java.htm) method.

```
/**
 * Shuts down this plug-in and discards all plug-in state.
 * 
 * @exception CoreException
 *                If this method fails to shut down this plug-in.
 * 
 * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
public final void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    try {

        /* Unregister as a save participant */
        if (ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() != null) {
            ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().removeSaveParticipant(this);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CoreException(new Status(IStatus.ERROR,
            getSymbolicName(), CommonUIStatusCodes.PLUGIN_SHUTDOWN_FAILURE,
            getShutdownErrorMessage(getPluginName()), e));
    } finally {
        super.stop(context);
    }
}
```

(obviously, do not use `CommonUIStatusCodes`)

Comment: Actually, my application does not use the Resource Plugin either :D  Any other chances?

Comment: @Mario: is it a pure osgi plugin then?

Comment: I've added some more info.  Now that I tought about it, I realize that probably there is no Eclipse way, because there is no Workbench.  I am creating my own stuff for UI, so I have to dispose of it myself.

Comment: @Mario: you are right, you only need to determine where that un-allocation can take place. I will have look at it tomorrow.